# Simple ST_WITHIN query returning no results

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, geospatial

I'm trying to get my head around Cosmos DB's `ST_WITHIN` function. I started out with something fairly complex but have had to whittle it down to something that I'm *certain* should work but doesn't.

Consider:

```sql
SELECT ST_WITHIN({ 'type': 'Point', 'coordinates': [ 0, 0 ] }, {'type':'Polygon','coordinates':[[[-150, -50], [-150, 50], [150, 50]]]}) FROM c
```

Why does this return an empty object for every record in `c`? That is, for 3 items in `c`, the results look like this:

```
[
    {},
    {},
    {}
]
```

At the very *least*, I would expect it to return `false` for every object rather than...nothing. But actually in this case I'd expect it to return `true`, since the point provided is within the polygon.

I expect I'm doing something quite obviously wrong, but I can't figure out what. I've already tried enabling `Point`, `Line`, and `Polygon` indexes on the collection to no avail.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, i reproduced your issue on my side,please see the statement in the [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/geospatial#querying-spatial-types).

> Similar to how mismatched types work in Azure Cosmos DB query, if the
>   location value specified in either argument is malformed or invalid,
>   then it evaluates to undefined and the evaluated document to be
>   skipped from the query results. If your query returns no results, run
>   ST_ISVALIDDETAILED To debug why the spatial type is invalid.

Then you could check the reason that `Each ring of a polygon must contain at least four points` with `ST_ISVALIDDETAILED` method.

[image]